# Eclipse PDT | PHP-Explorer remains in Project Focus (go into) after restart

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

after i "went into" a project in PHP-Explorer (Tree-View of Eclipse PDT) by choosing "go into" from the context menu, it remains in this focus after restart - even when i go to the top hierarchy before closing eclipse.

How can i make eclipse start with PHP-Explorer showing all Projects?

I'm not shure, but you should be able to reproduce the problem by doing something like this:

1. Right-click on some Project in PHP-Explorer and choose "Open in new Window"
2. Choose a nother Project in Window Nr.1 and choose "Go into"
3. Close both windows and restart Eclispe PDT

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit following file with text editor.
workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench\workbench.xml

Find
<input factoryID="org.eclipse.ui.internal.model.ResourceFactory" path="/xxx" type="4"/>
and replace it by
<input factoryID="org.eclipse.ui.internal.model.ResourceFactory" path="/" type="8"/>

I couldn't find other ways...